# ComponentWillReceiveProps giving multiples calls. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a big problem with the `ComponentWillReceiveProps`.

**What happens?**
I have the three components, that i pass the `props` from *component 1* to *component 2* and of the *component 2* i pass to *component 3*, where is really used..

Basically is: I pass the `props` of the *component 1* to use in the *component 3*

In the component 3, i make an ajax call with the news `props` using `ComponentWillReceiveProps`. But when i pass the `props` it makes multiples ajax instead just one..

I dont know why.. Can someone help me?

Component 1:

```js
render() {
    return ( 
    <Router>
      <Route exact path = "/"
      render = {
        (props) =>
        <Overview 
        { ...props}
         domainStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.domainStatusFiltered
        }
        subdomainStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.subdomainStatusFiltered
        }
        managerStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.managerStatusFiltered
        }
        countryStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.countryStatusFiltered
        }
        cityStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.cityStatusFiltered
        }
        squadNameStatusFiltered = {
          this.state.squadNameStatusFiltered
        }
        />} / >
      )
    }
```

Component 2:

```js
render(){
   return (
   <TwoColumnGrid>
     <Module className="mt-2" title="Team Status">
       <TeamStatus
         domainStatusFiltered={this.props.domainStatusFiltered}
         subdomainStatusFiltered={this.props.subdomainStatusFiltered}
         managerStatusFiltered={this.props.managerStatusFiltered}
         countryStatusFiltered={this.props.countryStatusFiltered}
         cityStatusFiltered={this.props.cityStatusFiltered}
         squadNameStatusFiltered={this.props.squadNameStatusFiltered} />
        </Module>
    </TwoColumnGrid>
  )
}
```

In the *Component 3*, i do a verify of the user logged and make the ajax according to your level:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        const firstName = localStorage.getItem('nameLoggedUser');
        const lastName = localStorage.getItem('lastNameLoggedUser');
        const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`.toLowerCase();

        const loggedUserIs = localStorage.getItem("user-role");

        if (loggedUserIs === 'full') {
            axios.get(`/api/squadsPeopleAll/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadNameStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    const getIds = res.data.map(i => i.id);
                    const people = Object.keys(getIds).length;

                    const getSquad = res.data.map(i => i.squad_name);
                    const unicSquads = Array.from(new Set(getSquad));

                    const squads = Object.keys(unicSquads).length;
                    this.setState({
                        people,
                        squads
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))

            axios.get(`/api/wfmskills/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        totalSkills: res.data.count,
                        loading: false
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/notupdated/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        totalNotUpdated: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2017/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2017: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2016/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2016: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2018/${props.managerStatusFiltered}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2018: res.data.count
                    });
                })
        }

        if (loggedUserIs === 'L4') {
            axios.get(`/api/squadsPeopleManager/${fullName}/${this.state.cityStatusFiltered}/${this.state.countryStatusFiltered}/${this.state.squadNameStatusFiltered}/${this.state.domainStatusFiltered}/${this.state.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                    const getIds = res.data.map(i => i.id);
                    const people = Object.keys(getIds).length;

                    const getSquad = res.data.map(i => i.squad_name);
                    const unicSquads = Array.from(new Set(getSquad));

                    const squads = Object.keys(unicSquads).length;
                    this.setState({
                        people,
                        squads
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))

            axios.get(`/api/wfmskills/manager/${fullName}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        totalSkills: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/notupdated/manager/${fullName}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        totalNotUpdated: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2017/manager/${fullName}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2017: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2016/manager/${fullName}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2016: res.data.count
                    })
                })
            axios.get(`/api/updated2018/manager/${fullName}/${props.cityStatusFiltered}/${props.countryStatusFiltered}/${props.squadStatusFiltered}/${props.domainStatusFiltered}/${props.subdomainStatusFiltered}`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        updated2018: res.data.count
                    }, () => this.setState({
                        loading: false
                    }));
                })
        }
  }
```

The problem is, for example: If I give the setState only in `subdomainStatusFiltered` it from multiple ajax calls and returns the result several times, I did a test and put a `console.log ('test')` it is rendered several times, I do not know why, or I'm using the wrong method and I do not know, look that it rerender several times... I just want to call a single time when I change some state, can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount() {
    // here you can use your API calls with this.props
}
```

If still you want use `componentWillReceiveProps` then you can do as below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!this.props.managerStatusFiltered && nextProps.managerStatusFiltered){
        // now you can use nextProps.managerStatusFiltered
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, have you compare `props` with `nextProps` to make sure props was different? `componentWillReceiveProps` does not guarantee the props was different. Instead, it'll be invoked everytime your component needs to re-render.

And secondly, I think the best way to do it is moving the async calls to the top level component and passing the response data to children that need it. This way you can avoid complex state check.

Answer (score -1):

If you want events to occur once and only once over the lifetime of a React component, you should use `componentDidMount`.

Please note that `componentWillReceiveProps` is a legacy lifecycle method and should not be used anymore in new projects. This method will soon only be available with the UNSAFE_ prefix when React 17 will be released. From the react documentation:

**UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)**

> **Note**:
>
> Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies,
> and for that reason it is going to be deprecated in the future.
>
> **If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an
> animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate
> lifecycle instead.**